# How to group by a column with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting

Thank you for your feedback in advance! I am working on time series data, which has 2 columns index converted to DateTime object. What I am dealing with looks like below:

[image]

I'm trying to parse out sales record by each store so that I can customize sales forecasting for each store. Any recommendations?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try the search function ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just filter out by Store?

Comment: Eventually, I want to make sales forecast on all stores. There are about 1000 stores and the sales history I'm using is from 2013 to current date

Answer (score 1):

You can either just query/slice the dataframe by the `'Store'` column, or do a `.groupby('Store')`., or set the index to be `['Store', 'Fiscal_Date']`. It's not really clear what you want to do. Perhaps this help?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fiscal_Date':['2013-12-01','2013-12-01','2013-12-02','2013-12-02'],
                    'Store':['A','B','A','B'],
                    'Sale':[12,143,23,21]})


df = df.set_index(['Fiscal_Date']).sort_index()


store_tables = {}
for store in list(df['Store'].unique()):
    filter_df = df[df['Store'] == store]
    store_tables[store] = filter_df.drop('Store',axis=1)
```

**Output:**

To get specific Store table, just call with the store name as the key:

```
print(store_tables['A'])
             Sale
Fiscal_Date      
2013-12-01     12
2013-12-02     23
```

Or Store 'B':

```
print(store_tables['B'])
             Sale
Fiscal_Date      
2013-12-01    143
2013-12-02     21
```

Comment: As far as I know, time series data must be indexed with datetime with one column (In this case, that column would be Sale). But because I have Store, Sales (2 columns), I am having trouble forecasting Sale. That is when I thought of grouping by each store to have separate Sale column indexed with Datetime

Comment: Ah ya. Then my solution should work for you as you can just drop the store column. Just be sure to keep track of which table is which. In fact, I just updated the code so you can do that

Answer (score 0):

df = name of dataframe

To get the sale value of a particular store:

`df["Sale"].loc[(df["Store"] == "StoreName")]`

Comment: This does not work because 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: You asked for sales by store

Comment: I believe this code should read `df.loc[(df["Store"] == "StoreName"), "Sale"]`. The method `.loc` takes 2 parameters eg. `df.loc["row identifier", "column identifier"]`.

Comment: @j__carlson the identifier to sale column is in the first part of code df["Sale"]

Comment: @LukeSimpson, I stand corrected. This will function as intended, but it is unnecessary to use `.loc` to mask a `series`.